# Estimate Total Heat Generation per LED for CFD boundary condition

Tags: led, heat

I am designing a lampshade to house a 240v 14W 6500K LED bulb and simulating the heat generated in and around the lampshade using CFD. I need to know how many watts each of the 26 LEDs is using but the MCPCB they're mounted on is film-coated and there's no access for my multimeter probes.

I have been running simulations based on 14W / 26 LEDs * .75 (ballpark watts lost as heat). This gives a Total Heat Generation value of ~.4W per LED. However, when I simulate the bulb with natural convection and an ambient temperature of ~22°C I am getting results >300°C. When I measured the surface temperature of the LEDS, they were ~78°C (again, ambient temperature ~22°C).

To rule out any errors in my simulation parameters, my question is:

- Is it possible to estimate watts per LED and subsequently a Total Heat Generation value based on stated bulb wattage/measured surface temperature/LED count?

In other words, based on the manufacturer's stated watt rating, is a Total Heat Generation value .4W per LED a good representation?

Comment: The listed power for that bulb is probably input power and the supply won’t be 100% efficient, you can try fewer watts at the LED string perhaps - that won’t fix 300 degrees though

Comment: @Bryan The PCB has a code printed on it ending in 15W. The bulb is sold as a 14.5W. Assuming the 15W means watts, does ~97% efficiency sound about right?

Comment: wow 97% sounds really good, I'd suspect that the people who designed the board and the people who designed the housing just didn't get the same memos from the marketing dept (who probably wrote "100W equivalent" on it). Without seeing anything related to it I'd outright guess 80% to start.

Comment: @Bryan So in desperation I pulled the bulb apart and the PCB is being supplied 100VDC-114VDC at 130mA, so the 14.5W is pretty much what it's consuming. And I meant to say that 300°C figure is what the simulation is returning, in real life they're peaking around 78°C. So either that MCPCB is using magic, or my simulation parameters are wrong :D

Comment: No, your simulation is incomplete. Power dissipation at the LED yields visible light and heat, which is dissipated by radiation, conduction, and convection. The LED's also probably directly emit infrared and possibly UV. Some energy may even be emitted electromagnetically through radio waves. Keep going with what you started by taking the lamp apart (be careful though!) To make PCB pads for soldering, with the light unplugged and with a razor blade knife, scrape the conformal coating etc down to copper to expose the traces on the PCB then polish to prepare for soldering.

Comment: Plug light back in until good and hot, then use thick work gloves to unscrew bulb and solder test wires in with a good soldering iron -- I like to use magnet wire, as it obscures the light less than the typical PVC insulated wire does, and it won't melt or smoke.

Comment: Then, you can screw the bulb back in and use alligator clips to take multimeter measurements without electrocuting yourself (keep left hand in pocket entire time, set it up, turn it on, write down measurements, turn it off, unplug, be wary of still-charged capacitors). The body of the bulb is actually a heat-sink in disguise, and wicks away the heat so the bulb survives. Learn about heat sink calculations.

Comment: Then you can use tiny NTC thermistors, also attached by magnet wire, glued in a line or a grid pattern to measure the actual gradients. NTC thermistors are really cheap, but don't get the teeniest ones -- they're impossible to work with.